# How to convert/modify nested map in list of maps when some entry name is found?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

Example:
This is how it looks in **yaml** structure:

```
    states:
      entries:
        NONE: 
          value: core.lookups.states.none
          readonly: true
        MINOR:
          value: core.lookups.states.minor
          readonly: true
        MAJOR: 
          value: core.lookups.states.major
          readonly: true
      readonly: true
```

This is ho it should look like after conversion:

```
    states:
      entries:
        - key: "NONE"
          value: core.lookups.states.none
          readonly: true
        - key:  "MINOR"
          value: core.lookups.states.minor
          readonly: true
        - key: "MAJOR"
          value: core.lookups.states.major
          readonly: true
      readonly: true
```

*Note*: There could be more entries, but the key "entries" is the same in every entry like:

```
        states:
          entries:
            - key: "NONE"
              value: core.lookups.states.none
              readonly: true
            - key:  "MINOR"
              value: core.lookups.states.minor
              readonly: true
            - key: "MAJOR"
              value: core.lookups.states.major
              readonly: true
          readonly: true
        states2:
          entries:
            - key: "NONE"
              value: core.lookups.states2.none
              readonly: true
            - key:  "MINOR"
              value: core.lookups.states2.minor
              readonly: true
            - key: "MAJOR"
              value: core.lookups.states2.major
              readonly: true
          readonly: true
```

*Note*: There could be more entries, but the key "entries" is the same in every entry like:

```
public static void hashMapper(Map<String, Object> lookups) throws ParseException
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : lookups.entrySet())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (key.equals("entries"))
            {
                //modify the entry into list
            }
            else if (value instanceof Map)
            {
                Map<String, Object> subMap = (Map<String, Object>) value;
                hashMapper(subMap);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(value));
            }

        }
    }
```

**This is what I've done so far. Every time when I find key with value of entries I should convert the entry inside. Also the states can have another parent key**

Comment: And how does it look like in Java? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Code code code, show me the code.

Comment: I added the code in the post.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, map `entries` would become a list?

Comment: Yes, it will be modified the given structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick demo how to use `YAMLFactory` from Jackson:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class YamlTest {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

    public static Map<String, State> convert(String yaml) throws Exception {

        Map<String, State> states = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(yaml, Map.class);

        for (String state : map.keySet()) {
            List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<>();
            Map<String, Object> statesMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.get(state);
            Map<String, Object> entriesMap = (Map<String, Object>) statesMap.get("entries");

            for (String entryKey : entriesMap.keySet()) {
                Map<String, Object> entryValueMap = (Map<String, Object>) entriesMap.get(entryKey);

                String value = (String) entryValueMap.get("value");
                Boolean readonly = (Boolean) entryValueMap.get("readonly");

                entryList.add(new Entry(entryKey, value, readonly));
            }

            Boolean readonlyState = (Boolean) statesMap.get("readonly");

            states.put(state, new State(entryList, readonlyState));
        }

        return states;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String input = "states:\n" +
                "  entries:\n" +
                "    NONE:\n" +
                "      value: core.lookups.states.none\n" +
                "      readonly: true\n" +
                "    MINOR:\n" +
                "      value: core.lookups.states.minor\n" +
                "      readonly: true\n" +
                "    MAJOR:\n" +
                "      value: core.lookups.states.major\n" +
                "      readonly: true\n" +
                "  readonly: true";

        Map<String, State> states = convert(input);
        String yamlOut = mapper.writeValueAsString(states);

        System.out.println(yamlOut);
    }
}

class State {

    public List<Entry> entries;
    public boolean readonly;

    public State(List<Entry> entries, boolean readonly) {
        this.entries = entries;
        this.readonly = readonly;
    }
}

class Entry {

    public String key;
    public String value;
    public boolean readonly;

    public Entry(String key, String value, boolean readonly) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.readonly = readonly;
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
---
states:
  entries:
  - key: "NONE"
    value: "core.lookups.states.none"
    readonly: true
  - key: "MINOR"
    value: "core.lookups.states.minor"
    readonly: true
  - key: "MAJOR"
    value: "core.lookups.states.major"
    readonly: true
  readonly: true
```

I used these dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I already have the map, there is no need of convert it from yaml into map. Also there can be more (key, value) pairs in the entries not just value and readonly. this part should be considered as a map.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Object> root = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,Object> states = new HashMap<>();
    root.put("states", states);
    Map<String,Object> entries = new HashMap<>();
    states.put("entries", entries);
    Map<String,Object> none = new HashMap<>();
    entries.put("NONE", none);
    none.put("value", "core.lookups.states.none");
    none.put("readonly", true);
    Map<String,Object> minor = new HashMap<>();
    entries.put("MINOR", minor);
    minor.put("value", "core.lookups.states.minor");
    minor.put("readonly", true);
    Map<String,Object> major = new HashMap<>();
    entries.put("MAJOR", major);
    major.put("value", "core.lookups.states.minor");
    major.put("readonly", true);
    states.put("readonly", true);
    System.out.println(root);
    System.out.println(convertRoot(root));
}

private static Map<String,Object> convertRoot(Map<String,Object> root) {
    Map<String,Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> e: root.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        Object value = e.getValue();
        if (key.startsWith("states") && value instanceof Map) {
            value = convertStates((Map<String,Object>)value);
        }
        result.put(key, value);
    }
    return result;
}

private static Map<String,Object> convertStates(Map<String,Object> states) {
    Map<String,Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> e: states.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        Object value = e.getValue();
        if (key.equals("entries") && value instanceof Map) {
            value = toList((Map<String,Object>)value);
        }
        result.put(key, value);
    }
    return result;
}

private static List<Object> toList(Map<String,Object> map) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> e: map.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        Object value = e.getValue();
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            Map<String,Object> elm
                    = new HashMap<>((Map<String,Object>)value);
            elm.put("key", key);
            value = elm;
        }
        result.add(value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

UPDATE: convert in-place

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Object> root = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,Object> states = new HashMap<>();
    root.put("states", states);
    Map<String,Object> entries = new HashMap<>();
    states.put("entries", entries);
    Map<String,Object> none = new HashMap<>();
    entries.put("NONE", none);
    none.put("value", "core.lookups.states.none");
    none.put("readonly", true);
    Map<String,Object> minor = new HashMap<>();
    entries.put("MINOR", minor);
    minor.put("value", "core.lookups.states.minor");
    minor.put("readonly", true);
    Map<String,Object> major = new HashMap<>();
    entries.put("MAJOR", major);
    major.put("value", "core.lookups.states.minor");
    major.put("readonly", true);
    states.put("readonly", true);
    System.out.println(root);
    convertRoot(root);
    System.out.println(root);
}

private static void convertRoot(Map<String,Object> root) {
    Map<String,Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String key: root.keySet().toArray(new String[root.size()])) {
        Object value = root.get(key);
        if (key.startsWith("states") && value instanceof Map) {
            convertStates((Map<String,Object>)value);
        }
    }
}

private static void convertStates(Map<String,Object> states) {
    Map<String,Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String key: states.keySet().toArray(new String[states.size()])) {
        Object value = states.get(key);
        if (key.startsWith("entries") && value instanceof Map) {
            states.put(key, toList((Map<String,Object>)value));
        }
    }
}

private static List<Object> toList(Map<String,Object> map) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> e: map.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        Object value = e.getValue();
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            Map<String,Object> elm
                    = new HashMap<>((Map<String,Object>)value);
            elm.put("key", key);
            value = elm;
        }
        result.add(value);
    }
    return result;
}
```